Field extension is normal if and only if it is the splitting field of a polynomial.
I'm struggling with a proof of a fact from my algebra class. I can not understand one step in my notes that I took long time ago and also I'd like to check if this solution is correct.
Def 1. Field extension $F \subset K$ is called normal if $\forall k \in K:g\in K$ where $g$ is a conjugate element of $k$.
I need to prove that field extension is normal iff $K$ is a splitting field of $f(x) \in F[x]$
Here are my thoughts about it:
$\Longrightarrow$ let's fix $\alpha_1, ... \alpha_n$ as a basis in Linear space $K$ over field $F$ and let $f_1, ... f_n$ be their minimal polynomials. all conjugates of $\alpha_1, ... \alpha_n$ also belong to $K$, so we can split $f_i$ over K $\implies$ $f=f_1f_2...f_n$ can be splitted over $K$ too. Now I wanna choose some other splitting field $L$ such that $F \subset L \subset K$. Then $\alpha_1, ... \alpha_n \in L$ (why?) so $K = <\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ... \alpha_n> \subset L \implies L = K$.
$\Longleftarrow$ this part is easier: let $a \in K$ and $f(x) \in F[x]$ be it's minimal polynomial. since $K$ is a splitting field over $F[x]$, $f(x)$ can be splitted (for simplicity suppose there are only 2 roots): $f(x) = \lambda(x-a)(x-d)$ where by definition $a, d \in K$ so conjugate element $d \in K$, q.e.d.
It would be very helpful if you could check my thoughts and also help me with my question in left-to-right part. Thank you!

For $\Rightarrow$ you have shown that the polynomial $f=f_1f_2 \cdot \dots \cdot f_n$ splits over $K$ because all roots of it belong to $K$. If we now take a splitting field $L$ of the polynomial $f$ over $F$ we know that $L$ is generated by the roots of $f$ (definition of a splitting field). Since these are all contained in $K$ we obtain $F \subset L \subset K$. But since $K$ is also generated by these roots and these are all contained in $L$, we obtain $L \subset K$ which shows $L=K$.

@Lukas, I guess you have a typo in your last sentence: "we obtain $K \subset L$". thank you, now I understand it (I forgot that L is generated by roots of f(x)). is my right-to-left part okay?

Yes, you are right. It should say $K \subset L$ in the last sentence.
For the other direction the argument is ok if you already know that every polynomial $f$ which has a root in $K$ splits in $K$. However, you only know that for the polynomial whose splitting field $K$ is. Therefore it depends on the other theorems that you already know whether this implication ("since $K$ is a splitting field over $F[x]$, $f(x)$ can be splitted") is correct.

Every splitting field is a finite extension. A normal extension is not necessarily finite.
